# Setting default values for Complex Properties - Backfilling database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have an MVC site using code first migrations which contains an Object called "Organisation" as below:

```
public class Organisation
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; } 
    public UserPermissions Permissions { get; set; }

}
```

And I am trying to implement user permissions for each of the areas on my site. As a result the **Permissions** property has been newly added above and is an object of type UserPermissions:

```
public class UserPermissions
{
    public PermissionLevel Contacts { get; set; }
    public PermissionLevel Messages { get; set; }
    public PermissionLevel Groups { get; set; }
    public PermissionLevel Data { get; set; }
}
```

Where **PermissionLevels** is an enum defined as:

```
public enum PermissionLevel
{
    Locked = 0,
    View = 1,
    Administrator = 2
}
```

I feel the structure of this implementation is fine and upon adding the migration EF creates a column in my dbo.Organisations table for each permission type (Permissions_Contacts, Permissions_Messages etc.).

The database however already has many Organisations and I wondered if there was a way of imposing a default. If I updated my database now all Permissions would be 0 (Locked), however I'd like the default to be different for each Permissions category e.g. Administrator rights for Contacts/Messages/Groups and Locked rights for Data because Data will be set up as and when a user requests it.

I will soon add functionality to the Admin tier of the site where the Organisations are created, and make the selection of UserPermissions mandatory for all areas, but I'd prefer not to have to go back through and manually change all permissions of the existing Organisations to be my defaults.

Is there a way of automatically imposing these defaults for the existing organisations within the database?

Comment: Have you tried using this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx , I don't know if this will work though

Comment: Thanks that's interesting I'd never seen that property. I'll try adding `[DefaultValue(typeof(PermissionLevels), PermissionLevels.Administrator)]` tag to the properties and see if it gets enforced on those already in the table. I assume getting and setting work fine after this?

Comment: It should be fine, as I said in my first comment, I don't know if it will edit the current db to those values though.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer is no. They initialise as 0 even with the defaultvalue property. Should be useful to enforce defaults then creating new Organisations though so thanks.

Comment: Ahh that is unfortunate, personally what I would do if you're just updating old data would be to do it in sql but best of luck to you in finding a solution in which you don't have to do that.

Comment: True point. I just thought it was quite interesting to find out if there was a different way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just set your default permissions in the constructor of your `Organisation` or `UserPermissions` object?

Something like:

```
public UserPermissions()
{
    Contacts = PermissionLevel.Locked;
    // etc
}
```

or

```
public Organisation()
{
    this.Permissions = new UserPermissions();

    if (this.Id == 0) // new object not yet persisted
    {
        this.Permissions.Contacts = PermissionLevel.Locked;
        // etc
    }
}
```

Based on comments:

For filling the existing data that is now out of sync with your model, you'll want to update your migration script to populate the new properties in your "up" script (the "down" script should not need modification I wouldn't think).

Basically in your up script you can either write update sql statements, or iterate through the objects via the context to manipulate their values in a more strongly typed manner.

Here's some information on getting started with migration scripts:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

I think your Up method could be modified to have something like this near the end:

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext)
{
    var orgs = context.Organisation;
    foreach (Organization org in orgs)
    {
        org.Permissions = new UserPermissions()
        {
            Contacts = PermissionLevel.Locked,
            // etc
        }
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: That would work for adding new Organisations which is good, but I'm more trying to avoid editing the permissions properties of those organisations already in my database....because they currently do not have permissions, I just added it, and upon updating the database their permissions will be treated as null and all be made 0 (Locked).

Comment: So your question specifically is how to back-fill the data, not how to impose a default going forward?  What EF model are you using? code first? db first? model first?  I think that could make a difference in what type of solution would be used to prefill your existing data.

Comment: Sorry I will edit to make the situation more clear now. I am using code first migrations.